# converting docx,doc to open xml using open xml sdk 2.0 its working fine with docx when converting doc its error that file has corrupted data

Tags: c#, using, openxml-sdk, doc

if (fileExt == ".doc" || fileExt == ".docx")
         {
          using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document,true))
             {
                 string docText = null;
             using (StreamReader sr = newStreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
                 {
                     docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                     lbtext.Text = docText;
                 }
             }
          }

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to open an old (2003?) format file using the SDK for the new format...

The solution is to convert the file into the new format before trying to open it. "WordConv.exe" is your friend...